# knob js animation value (transition)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-canvas, jquery-knob

I use knob js. This is readOnly, I would like to come up with the value and bar animation when the page first opens.

this is my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJCtv.jpg)

result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL0iO.jpg)

Comment: Can you update your code in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) instead of the  screenshot, so that anyone can edit that.. Also are you want to achieve this by using any other roundSlider plugin?

Comment: Yesterday you wrote: I dont want use svg. I want edit this code: cssscript.com/demo/pure-css-circular-percentage-bar. Because you can easily edit the back-end ???

Comment: Yes, but here it makes things easier to get input from the input.
<Input class = "value =" 75 ">
Knob, seeing work. All I want is the animated value.